# Trying to figure out UV Wrapping but it is not working

Tags: uv-image-editor

I thought for sure that I understood, but I guess I do not.

I "exported" - UV> Export UV Layout from the UV Editor, so that I could place materials via Photoshop to this exported layout - see attached image for the results - it's looks perfect to me, but the "shirt" obj does not refresh

[image: during edit mode]

[image: after switching to object mode no update]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. From everything that I have read and watched, this is how UV Wrapping works

Screenshot of the material for the shirt - I gave the shirt a new material, as what follows what I have read

[image]

This was the original material, but it was not working. That is why I deleted it and tried to add a new material

[image]

Originally, I was hoping to fix the black box around the badge, which lead to learning about UV mapping.

You (@moonboots), I re-imported the obj file, then I just had to plug in the original material and Blender knew what to do. The following is the Shading area and the object that is correctly UV mapped - thank you all for your help

[image: plugged in original texture]

Here's the result and thank you:
[image: you were correct]

Comment: Well, what does the material of the shirt look like? Is the texture you painted in Photoshop plugged in the material and is it using the UV map? Does the shirt even have a material?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the material of the shirt?

Comment: I have updated the post with the requested screenshot

Comment: You need to plug a Texture > Image Texture node into your Principled BSDF, and load the image in this Image Texture, otherwise Blender doesn't know it is supposed to project the image onto the surface

Comment: Added more context to my original question